# How to hide elements with specific attribute values with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a list like this

```
<ul>

<li language="English"> Australia </li>
<li language="English"> America </li>
<li language="French"> France </li>
<li language="French"> Canada </li>
<li langauge="German"> Germany </li>

</ul>
```

I just want to filter and display the list having language as English. How can I achieve this using Jquery?

And what would be the strategy if the li has multiple attributes like  `<li language="English,French"> Canada </li>`, I want to display Canada for both English as well as French language speaking country.

Appreciate if you post exact code as I already played with hide() and not() for a while now.

Comment: What? Do you want to hide the `language="English"` elements, or show them? If you want to show Canada as well, then add all the relevant attributes/attribute-values, and explain which should be shown and which hidden.

Comment: Refer this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16528895/500725)**

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
<li language="English"> Australia </li>
<li language="English"> America </li>
<li language="French"> France </li>
<li language="French English"> Canada </li>
<li langauge="German"> Germany </li>

$('li').not("[language*='English']").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Should go like this, using the "contains" attribute selector http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ -

```
$('li').not('[language*="English"]').hide();
```

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/caySY/

Comment: This wont work as it hid all the li elements. Some li dont have the language attribute. I dont want to touch them and leave as it is.

Comment: No, it couldn't have hid them all - please see the fiddle.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked, so what if I have two lists like this on a page and I want the filtering on one list and not on other

Comment: You would specify which list. For instance you would use $('ul').eq(0) for the first one, $('ul').eq(1) for the second one. The index number relates to which list in the page you need to refer to, or you can given each list an id.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple solution, using a `select` element to handle the language-choice:

```
$('#language').change(function(){
    // storing the language chosen in the select element
    var v = this.value;
    /* iterates over all li elements, and hides them,
       then filters the matched elements to see which elements
       contain the relevant language in the 'language' attribute: */
    $('ul li').hide().filter(function(i){
        return this.getAttribute('language').indexOf(v) !== -1;
    // shows the elements that contain the relevant language:
    }).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Uy3bz/).

Or a slightly different approach:

```
$('#language').change(function () {
    var v = this.value;
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        var l = this.getAttribute('language');
        return $(this).toggle(l.indexOf(v) !== -1);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Uy3bz/1/).

Both the above work with the following HTML:

```
<label for="language">Show:</label>
<select name="language" id="language">
    <option>English</option>
    <option>French</option>
    <option>German</option>
</select>
<ul>
    <li language="English">Australia</li>
    <li language="English">America</li>
    <li language="French">France</li>
    <li language="English French">Canada</li>
    <li language="German">Germany</li>
</ul>
```

Incidentally please note the corrected spelling of 'language' in the final `li` element.

Further, it'd be better to correct your HTML to use a valid (under HTML5) `data-*` attribute, such as `data-language` (to use the obvious):

```
<ul>
    <li data-language="English">Australia</li>
    <li data-language="English">America</li>
    <li data-language="French">France</li>
    <li data-language="English French">Canada</li>
    <li data-language="German">Germany</li>
</ul>
```

And the above code amended, to use that modified HTML:

```
$('#language').change(function(){
    // storing the language chosen in the select element
    var v = this.value;
    /* iterates over all li elements, and hides them,
           then filters the matched elements to see which elements
           contain the relevant language in the 'language' attribute: */
        $('ul li').hide().filter(function(i){
            return $(this).data('language').indexOf(v) !== -1;
            // shows the elements that contain the relevant language:
        }).show();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Uy3bz/3/).

```
$('#language').change(function () {
    var v = this.value;
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        var self = $(this),
            l = self.data('language');
        return self.toggle(l.indexOf(v) !== -1);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Uy3bz/2/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 1):

Just do this way

```
$("li:not([language*='English'])").hide();
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/4x8EJ/)**

### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li language="English"> Australia </li>
    <li language="English"> America </li>
    <li language="French"> France </li>
    <li language="French"> Canada </li>
    <li langauge="German"> Germany </li>
    <li language="English,French"> Canada1 </li>
</ul>
```

### OUTPUT:

```
<li language="English"> Australia </li>
<li language="English"> America </li>
<li language="English,French"> Canada1 </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Attribute selector:-

```
$('li[language]').hide(); //hide all with attribute language
$('li[language=English]').show() //show the ones with English
```

Comment: Why take two lines when you can do it with one?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple string in your language selector use the contains selector

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

```
$('li[language*="English"]').hide();
```